# Find executing callback with empty array, undefined variable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm having a strange problem, that started when I turned a .forEach into an actual for loop. What is happening, is when I push to the array, it breaks .find(). Unsure why, I don't think I'm mutating the array, because I'm assuming the previous find is done with the object and will start fresh the next time around, but maybe not?

Let me also say that I've tried putting a simplified attempt into a stackblitz 
 (using combineLatest, for loop with find) and I can't duplicate the issue.. (in the stackblitz you have to show the console) So I'm hoping someone can see something I'm not!

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xpzku2

Also, this.companyList is initialized blank elsewhere, it's not supposed to be filled in here, empty is good. Not always empty, but empty in this particular context. In fact, I didn't see the problem until it was empty.

Update: I've tried simplifying the logic with just the loops, finds, and push, and it still does it, but when I take nearly exact code and put it into stackblitz everything continues to work. Now I'm suspicious that it has to do maybe with the record I'm inserting is taken from the mstCompanyList which is populated via spread operator from the observable. This can't be right I'm feeling pretty stupid right now, so if anyone can help I'd appreciate it! :)

```
 combineLatest(routesObs, companiesObs, locationsObs, contractorObs).subscribe(([rList, cList, mList, cntList]) => { 
        this.routeList = [...rList];
        this.mstCompanyList = [...cList];
        this.mstLocationList = [...mList];
        this.mstContractorList = [...cntList];

        // At this point, companyList is an initialized, empty object.
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.companyList));

        // Generate a deduplicated version of company List, if the company's ID is already in the array, then skip, otherwise add. NOTE: This worked when it was a .forEach() unsure why it's not working now.
// The find starts returning an undefined object for cc, on the 2nd iteration (after the first push). I've tried removing the whole routeRecord piece and it still does it, working on trying to narrow this down better.
        for (var x = 0; x < this.routeList.length; x++) {

           // In the console this seems to show the routeList as in-tact and the same on each iteration.
          console.log(JSON.stringify(this.routeList)); 
          let routeRecord = this.routeList[x];

          // Here is the call that's acting strange, the docs for find say that it will not execute the callback if there is no object, but cc is coming back undefined. I exploded it out to a fat arrow function so I could put a console.log inside of it, to see for myself. THIS ONLY HAPPENS AFTER THE PUSH BELOW, BEFORE THE PUSH IT WORKS AS EXPECTED.
          let companyExists = this.companyList.find((cc) => { 
            console.log(JSON.stringify(cc));
            return cc.id == routeRecord.companyId 
          });

          // If the company is not in the array, add it. This breaks the above check, which is the meat 
          // of my question!
          if (companyExists == null) {
            let companyRec = this.mstCompanyList.find(cl => cl.id == routeRecord.companyId);
            this.companyList.push(companyRec);
          }
        }
```

Comment: If you can't provide a [mcve] then it'll be harder for others to help you.  In the absence of something reproducible, I'd suggest paring down your code to the smallest thing that shows the problem in your own environment, and post that minimal code in your question along with all the debugging output that convinces you something is wrong.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz Thanks I'll continue to simplify and edit throughout the day, it must be something simple.

Comment: Are you pushing `undefined` onto the list?  Can you add a `console.log(JSON.stringify(companyRec))` before you push it onto `this.companyList`?

Comment: @jcalz THAT'S IT!!! you're a genius! Write as an answer and I'll mark it as answer!

Comment: Now as to why it's undefined, that'll be my new mystery, but this question is solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at your code and the comments in it, you're saying that `this.companyList` starts out empty and then after you push `companyRec` onto it, your next call to `this.companyList.find(cc => ...)` has an `undefined` value of `cc`.  Since `find()` just calls the callback on each element of the list in turn (until the callback returns `true`), that must mean that `undefined` is an element of `this.companyList`.  And therefore it's likely that the `companyRec` you pushed onto the list was `undefined`.

So, once you verify that (`console.log(JSON.stringify(companyRec))` should help), you should see why `this.mstCompanyList` doesn't have an appropriate record matching the relevant `id` in it, since `.find()` returns `undefined` if it can't find what you ask for.

Since there was no minimum reproducible example here, it's hard for me to know how this is happening, but I suggest you use the [`--strictNullChecks` compiler option](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#--strictnullchecks) to help the compiler catch such possible problems with `undefined` before they happen at runtime.  The compiler should be warning you that `this.companyList.push(companyRec)` is bad because you haven't checked if `companyRec` is `undefined` first.

Anyway, hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: In case you are curious, this occurred because I have access role restrictions on the back end, that is, bring back only the company records that you are a member of. However, I forgot to implement the same restriction on another list, and when it went across the "security context", it didn't have a record to match.